# Stancl\Tenancy manage tenants users from central domain

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, multi-tenant, laravel-filament

I am looking for a way to manage all tenant users (users inside every tenant database) from the Stancl/Tenancy central domain.

When I am on the central domain, the app is connected to the landlord DB.
My expectation is to be able to create the user and store it in the chosen tenant database.
PS: I am using PostgreSQL with schemas instead of separated DB.

Answer (score 2):

The way I achieve it is:

1. Either you switch to tenant context and run your commands afterwards:

`$tenant = Tenant::find('some-id');`

`tenancy()->initialize($tenant);`

`// create your user for tenant here`

2. After finding the tenant, run your commands for the tenant like:
   `$tenant->run(function(){ // your code to create users here })`

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this as referenced [here](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/synced-resources-between-tenants) in the docs, is to create a CentralUser model that would be synced into your individual tenant models.

You'll also have a Pivot table that stores your Tenant~User relations.

Goodluck